# How to estimate measurement in selected location between a few sensors?

Tags: math, geometry, geospatial, physics, measurement

Let's say for example, that I have a few weather stations. Each station measures (e.g.) temperature and it's in different location.

Now I'm somewhere between those stations. I know their coordinates and I know my coordinates. How to estimate the temperature in my location?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One of simple methods - build some triangulation for weather stations
[image]

find triangle around your location, and use baricentric coordinates 
[image]

to find weights for infuence of every station. Then estimate temperature as weighted combination:

```
T(P) = w * T(A) + u * T(B) + v * T(C)
```

[Example of baricentric coordinates calculation](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/23743/whats-the-most-efficient-way-to-find-barycentric-coordinates)

Comment: It should be rather something like `T(P) = (w / areaOfABC) * T(A) + (u / areaOfABC) * T(B) + (v / areaOfABC) * T(C)`, right?

Comment: `w` is vertice weight in range 0..1, it has been already normalized with dividing by full area

Comment: For isotropic fields I would agree but for wheather stations is this extremly inaccurate as you need to take into account also the elevation normalized sun exposion and many other things ... weighting all the stations differently across the triangle area ... So the question is where and in what accuracy also how far are the stations ...

Comment: How about Shepard's method? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_distance_weighting
BTW Let's assume that they are pretty close to each other - like within 1 mile.

Comment: Inverse distance is reliable method too. But the first step - determine closest stations around the point.